# Get the average of nearly three days sql in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

The table like this:

```
DATE        ACTYPE  DICT
2017-01-01  A319    2
2017-01-01  A320    2
2017-01-02  A319    5
2017-01-02  A320    3
2017-01-03  A319    1
2017-01-03  A320    6
2017-01-04  A319    3
2017-01-04  A320    9
```

I want to get a result like this：

```
DATE        ACTYPE  DICT  DICT_MOV
2017-01-03  A319    1     2.666666
2017-01-03  A320    6     3.666666
2017-01-04  A319    3     3
2017-01-04  A320    9     6
```

DICT_MOV is nearly three days according to the average of the ACTYPE grouping.
E.g: DICT_MOV 3 = 5,1,3 average; DICT_MOV 6 = 3,6,9 average

Comment: I don't understand the calculation or why there are only two days in the result set.

Comment: The results should be 4 days, but I only wrote here for 2 days.The calculation E.g 3.666666 is 2017-01-01  A320    2, 2017-01-02  A320    3, 2017-01-03  A320    6; 3.666666=(2+3+6)/3     Sorry, it seems that I am not clear enough to describe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AVG` as an analytic function with a range window:

```
SELECT t.*,
       AVG( dict ) OVER (
         PARTITION BY actype
         ORDER BY "DATE"
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2' DAY PRECEDING
               AND     INTERVAL '0' DAY FOLLOWING
       ) AS dict_mov
FROM   your_table t
ORDER BY "DATE", actype
```

Comment: I think `RANGE INTERVAL '2' DAY PRECEDING` is the short form for this range. However, writing the full expression is easier to understand.

Comment: `INTERVAL '0' DAY FOLLOWING` should be equal to `CURRENT ROW` - again it's a matter of taste what you write.

Answer (score 0):

This query assume that (date, actype) is your table's PRIMARY KEY, and you want to get result for 3 nearest day - not consecutive. For consecutive date, you could use MTO's answer:

```
SELECT "date", actype, dict, 
    AVG(dict) OVER (
        PARTITION BY actype 
        ORDER BY "date"  
        rows BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS dict_mov
FROM table_name
ORDER BY "date", actype;
```

In case (date, actype) is not your table's PRIMARY KEY, then insted of table_name, you must use a subquery to calculate SUM(dict) GROUP BY "date", actype.

Comment: Primary keys are irrelevant to whether a function works or not.

Comment: If a day is skipped then this will get the average over the current day and the past 2 rows which could be more than 2 days previous. Similarly, if there are duplicate entries for a date/actype then this may get a smaller window than the current day back to 2-days previous.

Comment: @MT0 Yes, but because this caculate is using RANGE of ROW, so if (date, actype) is not UNIQUE, this query can't caculate for 3 `non-consecutive` days.

Comment: Delete the row `2017-01-03  A319    1` you will find that the output for `2017-01-04  A319` gives a moving average of `3.33333` (including `2017-01-01`) as it is 2-rows preceding rather than giving a result of `4` which is a 2-day window preceding.

Comment: @MT0 Yes, and we can call it **4 consecutive days** or  **3 non-consecutive days**. Yours solution is for **3 consecutive days**, and if that's what OP want then my answer is wrong. I had noted it in my answer too.

Comment: No, you cannot even call it 4 consecutive days. Add in a row `2018-01-04 A319 1` and a row `2019-01-04 A319 2` and you will get moving averages that span 1- and 2-years respectively. You cannot equate a row window with an equivalent size of range window.

Comment: @MT0 yes, you can call it any name like **n consecutive days/years**, but it still be **3 non-consecutive days**. And IMO it should be one `acceptable bussiness logic`. It maybe wrong in some case, maybe right in other case.